# Python Packaging: Install pre-compiled binary alongside package

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a Python package which comes with some pre-compiled binaries (yes, I know this is not ideal but it's for internal use only).

What is the correct way to use setuptools / distutils to install these binary files alongside my Python scripts, and also ensure they are symlinked from e.g. /usr/local.

I know how to do this for Python files with e.g. `scripts` or `console_scripts`, but neither of those seem to fit my use-case.

Comment: Look up [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files), it could help, but not recommended. Really you should look into the packaging system of the Linux distribution (_apt_, _yum_, _pacman_, etc.).